# Show Upsell Product in product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.1

i would like to show only the upsell products in product detail page, the issue is when i hide the upsell from Catalog and Search also it hide from product detail page, how i can show the update only in product details page?

Thank you

Magento ver. 2.0.10

Comment: how to get the upsell product collection